# Links in Community Bulletin should be easily identifiable

Tags: bug, design

On our *main* site, there is no styling at all for links in the community bulletin:

[image]

On our meta site, they are merely in bold.

[image]

In neither case the expected "language" of different colour, hover effect or underline is present.